# JAXB @XmlAnyElement with XmlAdapter does not make a call to the unmarshal method

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, moxy

I am trying to unmarshal the `XML` and map it to the Java POJO. My XML can have some of the user-defined elements which can be random so I would like to store them. After researching I found that I can use `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)`. I am trying to use the `XMLAdapter` along with the `@XmlAnyElement` but for some reason, the method `unmarshal` within my `XMLAdapter` is not being called at all due to which I am unable to map the `user-defined` fields.

Can someone please explain to me how to `unmarshal` the `user-defined` fields to my `Map<String,Object>` for the `marshalling` everything is working fine and I am using the approach [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32483762/7584240). But `unmarshalling` is not being called at all which is bit confusing for me.

Following is my `XML` which needs to be `unmarshalled`. (Please note that the `namespace` can be dynamic and user-defined which may change in every xml):

```
<Customer xmlns:google="https://google.com">
  <name>Batman</name>
  <google:main>
    <google:sub>bye</google:sub>
  </google:main>
</Customer>
```

Following is my `Customer` class to which `XML` needs to be `unmarshalled`;

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer", propOrder = {"name", "others"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

  private String name;

  @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestAdapter.class)
  private Map<String, Object> others = new HashMap<>();
  
  //Getter Setter and other constructors
}
```

Following is my `XMLAdapter (TestAdapter)` class which will be used for `marshalling` and `unmarshalling` the `user-defined` fields. The `unmarshalling` method is not being called at all. However the `marshalling` method works as expected based on [the code provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32483762/7584240).

```
class TestAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Wrapper, Map<String,Object>> {

  @Override
  public Map<String,Object> unmarshal(Wrapper value) throws Exception {
    //Method not being called at all the following SYSTEM.OUT is NOT PRINTED
    System.out.println("INSIDE UNMARSHALLING METHOD TEST");
    System.out.println(value.getElements());
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Wrapper marshal(Map<String,Object> v) throws Exception {
    return null;
  }
}

class Wrapper {
  @XmlAnyElement
  List elements;
}
```

I have used the `package-info.java` file and it has been filled with following contents:

```
@jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://google.com", elementFormDefault = jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package io.model.jaxb;
```

I researched a lot but could not find any answer which does something similar. Also, tried a lot of things but none worked. Hence, posting the same here and looking for some suggestion or workaround.

I have few doubts with regards to `unmarshalling`:

1. Why my `XMLAdapter TestAdapter.class` `unmarshal` method is not being called during the unmarshalling?
2. How can I `unmarshal` the XML fields which can appear randomly with namespaces?
3. Am I doing something wrong or is there something else I should do to read the namespaces and elements which appear dynamically?

```
*** FOLLOWING IS EDITED SECTION BASED ON RESPONSE FROM Thomas Fritsch ****
```

Based on the response I have edited my class but still not working as expected:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer", propOrder = {"name", "others"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

  private String name;

  @JsonIgnore
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestAdapter.class)
  private List<Object> others;

  @XmlTransient
  @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
  private List<Element> another = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

So what's happening is that if I use `@XmlTransient` then the field `another` will not be populated during the `unmarshalling` and I need to keep it `@XmlTransient` because I do not want it during the `marshalling` similarly I have made `@JsonIgnore` for `Map<String, Object> others` because I do not need it during the `unmarshalling` but both things are conflicting with each other and not able to obtain the the required output.

My main goal is to convert the `XML` file to `JSON` and vice versa. For the above mentioned `XML` file I would like to obtain the following output in `JSON`:

```
{
  "Customer": {
    "name": "BATMAN",
    "google:main": {
      "google:sub": "bye"
    }
  }
}
```

Similarly when I convert this `JSON` then I should get the original `XML`.

Following is my `Main.class`:

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException, JsonProcessingException {

    //XML to JSON
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customer.xml");
    final XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    final XMLStreamReader streamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
    final Customer customer = unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamReader, Customer.class).getValue();
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final String jsonEvent = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(customer);
    System.out.println(jsonEvent);

    //JSON to XML
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out a lot of things, I was able to get it working.  Posting the solution for the same so it can be helpful to someone in the future.

I have used `Project Lombok` so you can see some additional annotations such as `@Getter, @Setter, etc`

`Method-1:`

As mentioned @Thomas Fritsch you have to use the `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` with `List<Element>` I was using with the `Map<String, Object>`.

`Method-2:`

You can continue to use `Map<String,Object>` and use `@XmlPath(".")` with adapter to get it working. Posting the code for the same here: (I have added one additional field `age` other that everything remain the same)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer", propOrder = {"name", "age", "others"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Customer {

  @XmlElement(name = "name")
  private String name;

  private String age;

  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestAdapter.class)
  @XmlPath(".")
  private Map<String, Object> others;
}
```

Following is the `TestAdapter.class` posting the same for reference. When you `unmarhsal` the method `unmarshal` in `TestAdapter` will get called and you can do anything you need.

```
class TestAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Wrapper, Map<String, Object>> {

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> unmarshal(Wrapper value) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("INSIDE UNMARSHALLING METHOD TEST");
    final Map<String, Object> others = new HashMap<>();

    for (Object obj : value.getElements()) {
      final Element element = (Element) obj;
      final NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();

      //Check if its direct String value field or complex
      if (children.getLength() == 1) {
        others.put(element.getNodeName(), element.getTextContent());
      } else {
        List<Object> child = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
          final Node n = children.item(i);
          if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
            List childElements = new ArrayList();
            childElements.add(n);
            wrapper.elements = childElements;
            child.add(unmarshal(wrapper));
          }
        }
        others.put(element.getNodeName(), child);
      }
    }

    return others;
  }

  @Override
  public Wrapper marshal(Map<String, Object> v) throws Exception {
    Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
    List elements = new ArrayList();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> property : v.entrySet()) {
      if (property.getValue() instanceof Map) {
        elements.add(new JAXBElement<Wrapper>(new QName(property.getKey()), Wrapper.class, marshal((Map) property.getValue())));
      } else {
        elements.add(new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(property.getKey()), String.class, property.getValue().toString()));
      }
    }
    wrapper.elements = elements;
    return wrapper;
  }
}

@Getter
class Wrapper {

  @XmlAnyElement
  List elements;
}
```

Although it works for specific cases, I am seeing one problem by using this approach. [I have created a new post for this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648941/jaxb-moxy-unmarshalling-assigns-all-field-values-to-mapstring-object-rather-th)
If I get any response for that issue then I will try to update the code so it can work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The `Map` type of your `others` property is not suitable for `@XmlAnyElement`.

According to the its javadoc the [`@XmlAnyElement` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html)
is meant to be used with a `List` or an array property
(typically with a `List` or array of `org.w3c.dom.Element`).
May be you have confused this with the [`@XmlAnyAttribute` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyAttribute.html)
which indeed is used with a `Map` property.

Hence in your `Customer` class the `others` property without using an adapter would look like this:
name;

```
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private List<Element> others = new ArrayList<>();
```

And the `others` property with using an adapter should look like this:

```
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestAdapter.class)
    private List<MyObject> others = new ArrayList<>();
```

When doing this way, then JAXB will actually call your adapter.
The adapter's job is to transform between `Element` and `MyObject`.

```
public class TestAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Element, MyObject> {

    @Override
    public MyObject unmarshal(Element v) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Element marshal(MyObject v) throws Exception {
        ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for taking your time and responding. Also for the right explanation. I understood now how to do `unmarshalling` for the unknown elements that appear in the `XML`. But I have one doubt: Does this mean that the original `TestAdapter` that I have will have an empty `unmarshalling` method? Because I need that class and the `marshalling` method because I am using `Map<String, Object>` for the `marshalling`.

Comment: Also, does this mean that I need to create one more variable within the `Customer.class` as `others` variable I need it to be in `Map<String, Object>` because I am using this during `marshalling` and this is set by `Jackson @AnySetter` which needs in the `Map<String, Object>` type and during the `marshalling` I need to provide in that type. Also, in the new `TestAdapter` the `marshalling` method has to be empty because I need the `marshalling` method from the old `TestAdapter` with `Map<String,Object>` so I am bit confused on how to handle both the things without creating additional `Adapter`.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 So may be you need both variables in your `Customer` class.
Also remember you can annotate one of them by `@JsonIgnore`
so that it will be ignored Jackson. And you can annotate
the other by `@XmlTransient` so that it will be ignored by JAXB.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I will try to do it and if I run into an issue I will contact you :)

Comment: I tried with the `@JsonIgnore` and `@XmlTransient` but it's gonna give me the wrong output. My requirement is that I have to convert my file from `XML->JSON` and `JSON->XML`. For this I need to use the same `Customer` class for both `Marshalling` and `Unmarshalling`. If I use `@JsonIgnore` on `List<Element> others` then the `Jackson` will not use this during the creation of `JSON` but it will have the `elements` that I populated during the `unmarshalling` similarly if I use the `@XmlTransient` on the `List<Element> another` then during the `unmarshalling` it would not populate the information.

Comment: I have edited the question with the updated code based on your response. If you get a chance please have look at this and provide your suggestion on how to tackle this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, Finally I was able to get it working using the `Map<String,Object>` only but there is one more small problem that I am facing. I have created a new post for it. If you get a chance can you please have look and provide your suggestions? It would be really helpful if you can provide some explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648941/jaxb-moxy-unmarshalling-assigns-all-field-values-to-mapstring-object-rather-th